# How to setup Lumberjack (logstash forwarder) in redhat linux

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-forwarder

I am using Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana (ELK stack) for visualizing my perfmon logs. My logs were copied manually from another redhat linux box to my local linux box and being parsed. Now i would like to automate this using lumberjack but i'm not getting any relevant information to work with lumberjack. automate in the sense would like to get the logs from remote linux box instead of manual copying.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use logstash itself to forward the logs to your central logstash server.

However, I'd recommend looking at installing logstash-forwarder(*https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder*). Binaries are available from https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash (*at the bottom of the page*)